# Org links file name encoding issue

Tags: org-mode, character-encoding, org-link, filenames

Inspired by [John Kitchin's presentation](https://youtu.be/5haX95nk02E) of org-links features in Org-mode 9, I tried to implement a simple functionality for "file" links. Since I am working on several machines, I wanted the link face to show if  file exists on disk. So in `org-link-set-parameters` func for "file" I've put this simple code:

```
:face '(lambda (path) (if (file-exists-p path)
                          '(:foreground "green")
                        '(:foreground "red")))
```

It works just fine unless file has Polish characters in its name ("ąęćłóśżź"). Especially after editing the link description with `org-insert-link` with cursor on the link it's face becomes red (as non existent file), and the path becomes for example like this (assuming the file name is "żółć.org"):

```
[[file:%C5%BC%C3%B3%C5%82%C4%87.org]]
```

I was changing the value of `file-name-coding-system` variable but without any impact for described behaviour.

When I change value of the `:follow` key to `'(lambda (path) (message "%s" (file-exists-p path)))` it returns "t". I assume then that it has something to do with filtering file name by different emacs functions but I can't find which would be responsible for wrong behaviour of the ":face" parameter.

I'd appreciate any help to fix that.

Comment: Whatever method you're using to create the "file" link has run `org-link-escape` on the filename, so you should run `org-link-unescape` to get back the original.

Comment: @rpluim I was going to write something similar (referring to `url-encode-url` instead of `org-link-escape`). You should consider transforming your comment into an answer.

Comment: You should not play around with `file-name-coding-system`. If you do so in spite of the warning you can get problems with names of files created and saved with Emacs.

Comment: I suspect `url-encode-url` and `org-link-escape` are identical except when they're not :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `org-link-unescape` to get back the original filename? Something like:

```
:face '(lambda (path)
         (if (file-exists-p (org-link-unescape path))
             '(:foreground "green")
           '(:foreground "red"))))
```

Comment: BTW, if this works, you might consider filing a bug with org-mode, as the path argument should be the same in both the `:follow` and `:face` cases.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. (I haven't filed any bug before, will have to check this out)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried, and an Org-mode file with this content works just fine:

`[[file:żółć.org]]`

`C-c o` works as expected and visits the file.  For some reason `C-c o` works with the escaped characters as in your example, but I get an error `Error during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 33) signaled (error "Not enough arguments for format string") [2 times]` in `*Messages*` with your example.

Comment: That is not an answer to the question. I think everything essential you wrote is clear to the OP. You should consider to delete this answer.